# How is Spring appConfig.java class working

Tags: java, spring

I have the following Controller method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/manager/exportXls_{userID}_{stringMonth}_{stringYear}", 
               method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String downloadXls(@PathVariable String userID, @PathVariable String stringMonth,
                          @PathVariable String stringYear, Model model) {
    return "excelview";
}
```

So I was searching for the "excelview". Of course I was seeking it would be a template like normally. But I could not find it in the template folder.

So I was thinking somewhere this Excel has to be created.

So finally I found a class called `XlsView.java`
But now I was thinking how is this class called.
So now I found the following in class `AppConfig.java`

```
@Bean(name = "excelview")
public XlsView xlsView() {
    return new XlsView();
}
```

Here the class gets called. `@Bean` maybe means that it gets managed by Spring.
`XlsView.java` extends `AbstractXlsView` which comes from Spring Framework. That could be the reason that `renderMergedOutputModel()` Method is automatically called and which finally calls method `buildExcelDocument()` which creates the Excel.

I just over this project so I was really surprised how it is working. Can someone explain me more about this Spring feature and how it works. Does it only work in `AppConfig.java` class. Or could I put it somewhere else.  Thanks.

Comment: I have posted an answer , let me know in case you need more clarification on how view resolver works

Comment: Thx. What is a bean. A controller class is no bean. Why not?? Is there a good Spring tutorial ? I know the one from the Spring website, but it is soooo much information, I takes me ages to read this. For me there is so much magic what Spring framework is doing.

Comment: And Needs this class to be called AppConfig  ??? Or how does Spring find the ViewResolver ??

Comment: I have updated my answer  let me know if it works for u. and if it did kindly upvote or accept the answer.

Comment: I have updated my answer see if that helps u

Answer (score 0):

This bean is configured by Spring Boot it seems, so it should be more than possible to autowire this bean without a problem using a qualifier to specifically refer to this instance. This bean has a public modifier so you shouldn't have a problem accessing it outside of the scope of AppConfig.

```java
@Autowrited
@Qualifier("excelview")
private XlsView view;
```

Answer (score 0):

So I believe somewhere in your Project you must have defined a bean

```
@Bean
  public ViewResolver beanNameViewResolver() {
      BeanNameViewResolver resolver = new BeanNameViewResolver();
      return resolver;
  }
```

This basically resolve the return type of below code i.e.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/manager/exportXls_{userID}_{stringMonth}_{stringYear}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String downloadXls(@PathVariable String userID, @PathVariable String stringMonth,
        @PathVariable String stringYear, Model model) {
    return "excelview"; //This will resolve as a bean
}
```

By resolving it to bean name which is basically defined as

```
@Bean(name = "excelview")
public XlsView xlsView() {
    return new XlsView(); //This is the bean that is returned by the spring
}
```

now your class XlsView must be extending Spring class `AbstractXlsView` also overriding the default behavior of `buildExcelDocument` method which basically set the response mime type which is an excel and also the content which is to be put inside it.

```
public class XlsView extends AbstractXlsView {

  @Override
  protected void buildExcelDocument(Map<String, Object> model, Workbook workbook,
                                    HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
```

**

### Updates

**

1. **`@Component`**  generic annotation for any class to be declared as spring bean i.e. Managed by spring.
2. **`@Repository`** Special case of @Component for persistence bean
3. **`@Service`**    Special case of @Component for service bean
4. **`@Controller`** Special case of @Component for presentation(Controller)
   layer (spring-mvc) Capability to Map method with incoming Url
   request

more details http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/stereotype/Controller.html

Spring home page is the best tutorial for most of your question.

your AppConfig can be named as any thing, I suggest you must try that, rename it to MyAppConfig and restart your spring/spring boot application.
Basically here **`@Configuration`** is the one that does the magic to mark this class as  bean container it do not depend on class name.
it Indicates that a class declares one or more @Bean methods and may be processed by the Spring container to generate bean definitions and service requests for those beans at runtime.
link for learning
https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot

Comment: the name of the class has to be AppConfig ?? MyAppConfig is not possible right ??  And could you provide a link for tutorial . Thx